# piling up of requests in the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, request, client

I am sending 10 requests from the client to the server and putting a sleep after every request. But the request is not reaching the server immediately.
i.e, suppose request 1 is sent from client to server at time t1 
              request 2 is sent from client to server at time t2 and so on till request 10 is sent from client to server at time t10.
But all the 10 requests are reaching the server after time t10. Somewhere all the requests are getting piled up at the client until the last request and sending all the 10 requests to the server after time t10 .Why does it happen.
Here is the code for the client.

```
var request = require('request');
var sleep = require('sleep');
require('console-stamp')(console, '[ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss.l]');
var myObj = {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"};
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);


for(var a = 1; a<=10;a++){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8081/reqSer1/' + myJSON + '/' + a;
    console.log("request send");
    request.get(url , function (error, response) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log(response.body);

        // Print the response status code if a response was received

    });
    sleep.sleep(2);

}
```

Comment: `These calls will block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js' event loop!` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep)

Answer (score 0):

From the [sleep](http://npmjs.com/package/sleep) npm documentation:

> These calls will block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js'
>   event loop!

---

If you need to bound concurrency as to not overwhelm your server you should be able to:

- **Use a pool** - this should allow for you to configure the maximum number of requests allowed, this will allow you to strictly control how many connections you have open to your server so you don't overwhelm it (i'm not familiar enough with node to recommend best practice for this)